# For loop inside function executing only once

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm facing a problem that I have never encountered, I do invoke a function that contains a for loop many times from another function, but the latter is only executing once and I don't know what I did wrong.

here is the function that contains the for loop.

```
def check_neutre(word):
   global f4
   i = 0
   neutre = []
   print(word)
   for ligne in f4:
      neutre.append(ligne.strip())
   print(len(neutre))
   return "done"
```

f4 is a file variable opened at the top.

and here the function that calls it

```
def check_words(words):
    polarite = 0
    exist = False
    for word in words:
        print(check_neutre(word))

check_words(words)
```

words variable is a list of words.

[image: the output showing that the loop is executed only once]

the output above shows that the loop is executed only once

Comment: After looping `f4` for the first time, the file pointer is in the end and the loop never executes. You can try `f4.seek(0)` before the loop

Comment: But, why are you looping the whole file for each word? Why not loop once and then use the `neutre` list?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yess, this is what i plan to do, i'll declare a global neutre list and reuse it.

Comment: Don't declare global, pass it as parameter to the function

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for looping over each line of the file, and in your code you just loop it all at once

you can change to this in the start of the file:

```py
f4_lines = f4.readlines()
```

and use the global of `f4_lines` instad of `f4`

If it is a large file maybe there is another solution cause this will loads the file into the memory